# Implementation Issues with Log4j in Eclipse EMF RCP Using Java 17 and not OSG

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, log4j2, eclipse-emf

I'm working with Eclipse EMF RCP using Java 17 and trying to implement a logging system using Log4j. Despite various attempts, I'm unable to get it to work, including the creation of a directory for saving log messages. I've set up a standard Log4j2.xml configuration in the src folder and created a static Log4j instance with a loggerManager in the class that should generate log messages, but nothing seems to function. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to use this standard file log4j2.xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="LogFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>`
```

and tried to put this in the class.
`import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class MyClass {
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);`

I hope at least to get somme messages log in the logs/app.log and to create a view to read these messages